# Space complexity using the malloc function

Tags: c, malloc

Here's a function, I want to understand it's space complexity:

```
void func_test(int n)
{
    int *p;
    for (int i=0; i<=n; i++)
    {
        p=malloc(sizeof(int)*i);
        for (int j=0; j<i; j++) *(p+j)=j; //just to insert some numbers to p
        free(p);
    }
    return;
}
```

I know that in total I allocated sizeof(int)*n^2 bytes, but before I allocated a memory I "free" it. 
So, is the space complexity O(n^2) or O(1)?

Thanks, Tamir.

Answer (score 3):

It's O(n). You never allocate more than the space required to hold n `ints`. The reason is precisely because of what you noted. You free the memory in each iteration. Memory, unlike time, can be recycled.

Comment: Why is it O(n) if I free the space which holds n ints?

Comment: I mean, if we counted the space of n ints why wouldn't we count the space of n-1 ints, n-2 ints, and so on to 1?

Comment: @Tamir: because your code needs that much space to work. Although a good compiler might notice your inner loop and the allocation is pointless and completely remove it.

Comment: @Olaf: Thanks mate! got it!